# can not mount romfs image

Tags: linux, mount, rom

with mount version 2.21.2 I get this error every time I try to mount a romfs image

```
sudo mount -t romfs mlsrc.img mp/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'romfs'
```

I am running arch linux with kernel 3.4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Arch Kernel has been compiled without romfs support, so one must compile the kernel themselves with romfs support. Thank you to gtkmanfred on the arch linux irc channel #archlinux  @ freenode. He pointed me to something called the 
ABS: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System
here is how to use it to build the kernel: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Arch_Build_System

Answer (score 0):

`romfs` isn't a filesystem type that mount recognizes.  Try `mount -o loop mlsrc.img mp/`.

Comment: Same thing happens, unknown filesystem type 'romfs'.